# Getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" in Java

Tags: java

The output is supposed to be each word of the array printed backwards with their own lines

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         String [] list = {"every", "nearing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value"};
         String reverse = "";
         int length = list.length;
         for(int j=0; j<list.length; j++)
         {
            String word = list[j];
            for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
            {
                reverse = reverse + word.charAt(i);
            }
            System.out.println(reverse);
         }

    }
}
```

but I keep getting this message

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String 
    index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    enter code here`at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a tiny bit. Don't rely on temporary variables that do not improve the readability of your code. Do try and use `for-each` loops (they improve readability). Applying those two points, gives us

```
String[] list = { "every", "nearing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value" };
for (String word : list) {
    for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

which is based on your original code. Personally, I would *prefer* to use `StringBuilder` and its' `reverse()` method. Like,

```
for (String word : list) {
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder(word).reverse());
}
```

**or** in Java 8+, with a `map` like

```
Arrays.stream(list).map(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse())
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Maybe he is restricted to use third party libraries. But is good to test / compare

Comment: @Rcordoval No third party libraries here. Just pure Java 5+ and 8+ examples.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I mean it sounds like school homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
```

The `length` value you are using above is the length of the `list` array, not the word.

Remember to empty reverse word after each loop:

```
        System.out.println(reverse);
        reverse = "";
```

if you don't flush you'll get:

```
yrev
yrevgnirae
yrevgniraegnikceh
yrevgniraegnikcehdoo
yrevgniraegnikcehdoodnat
yrevgniraegnikcehdoodnateula
```

instead of:

```
yrev
gnirae
gnikceh
doo
dnat
eula
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the provided arguments are valid in   Main.java:13. Check that the provided offset points to a valid index and that the count argument does not point to indices greater than the size of the string itself.

An alternate:

```
public  String[]  reverseString(String[] words)
{
    String[] reverse=new String[words.length];

    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    {   
        //added for setting element as emptyString instead of null
        reverse[i] = "";
        for(int j=words[i].length()-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            reverse[i]+=words[i].substring(j,j+1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse));
    return reverse;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 11, change

```
int i = length-1;
```

to

```
int i = word.length()-1;
```

and the exception will go away.